# Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported

Tags: support, bug

When I try to login into any stackexchange site using my WordPress blog, I'm seeing this message:

```
Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported.
```

Please fix or tell me what I can do in my blog's settings to fix this.

And if you can tell me how to fix it in my blog's settings, then how about displaying this information next to the error message.

## I'd like to post this on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ but I can't login ... :-(

Update 1: This is probably a duplicate of [Wordpress OpenID: Redirects on POST requests that are to untrusted servers is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245329/wordpress-openid-redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-no)

Just like Antonio, I also have a custom domain which is the primary domain for my blog.

When I try to connect to my blog via HTTPS, I get a security exception: `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` because my blog `blog.pdark.de` doesn't match the wildcard certificate `*.wordpress.com`.

Comment: You're not the only one with this issue. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245329/wordpress-openid-redirects-on-post-requests-that-are-to-untrusted-servers-is-no

Comment: @Bart: I'd like to vote on the issue but I can't login ...

Comment: It's fine to keep this post here though. It's not off-topic on this site, and employees/devs are here as well.

Comment: For me that was because in my SimpleId installation, I forgot to use https scheme in the SIMPLEID_BASE_URL (was http:)